# GCC map file address for ISR different than memory value

Tags: dictionary, gcc

An address for an ISR shown in the GCC map is 0x00001328.

```
.text.USART0_RX_IRQHandler
            0x00001328       0xe4 ./Source/interrupts_new.o
            0x00001328                USART0_RX_IRQHandler
```

However, the value actually loaded into the ISR vector at 0x0000006C is 0x00001329.

0x00000060  000012ED 00001301 00001315 **00001329**  í...........)...

This is the first time I've noticed this (or even looked). Is the ok ?  Is this an alignment issue, or a Thumb issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It shows the uC that the ISR uses the THUMB instruction set.

Even addresses - ARM, odd - THUMB.

Everything is correct

The actual routine is at the addr & 0xffffff0c address  - ie with the last two bits zeroed.